# How to return a string of fixed length in python

Tags: python, string

I have a field of the following format : `16,paul920140526`, i.e. `count +`, `+ name` `+ Id` `+ date` `+ space` of 12 characters.

Currently I was returning it by doing the following:

```
def formatField(self) :  
    self.Id = self.getNextId()  
    self.cnt = self.getCount()  
    return(self.cnt+','+self.Id+'            ')
```

Here `getNextId` returns `Id` , `getCount` returns `count` (in the form of a string). However, I realized hard coding the 12 space characters was a bad idea because when the `id` increments from 9 to 10, i.e. a double digit number, the space should decrease from 12 to 11 characters. How should I ensure the whole Field remains of fixed length?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
return(self.cnt+','+self.Id+'            ')
```

to

```
s = str(self.cnt)+','+self.Id+'            '
return s[:13]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest case, if you are already padding with spaces, you can use Python array slicing to get the right length.

For example:

```
myWidth=30 # For example, this depends on how 'wide' you want the string to be.
myString = self.cnt+','+self.Id+'            '
return mystring[:MyWidth]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `ljust()` function

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Answer (score 0):

All other options are valid (my taste goes towards `.ljust()`) but for completeness, I'll add the following one:

```
def formatField(self, length=30):
    self.Id = self.getNextId()
    self.cnt = self.getCount()

    field = str(self.Id) + ',' + str(self.cnt)
    field += ' ' * max(0, length - len(field)

    return field
```